# getting error while deploying firebase cloud pub-sub code

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

while deploying pub-sub code on firebase i'm getting following error :

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/build/src/pubsub.js:527
    async *listSchemas(view = schema_1.SchemaViews.Basic, options) {
          ^
```

I'm not getting why this error is occurring.

following is the code:

```
exports.publish = async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.topic || !req.body.message) {
    res.status(400).send('Missing parameter(s); include "topic" and "message" properties in your request.');
    return;
  }

  console.log(`Publishing message to topic ${req.body.topic}`);

  const topic = pubsub.topic(req.body.topic);

  const messageObject = {
    data: {
      message: req.body.message,
    },
  };
  const messageBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(messageObject), "utf8");

  try {
    await topic.publish(messageBuffer);
    res.status(200).send("Message published.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i've added the code

Comment: When and where do you call `publish` from? is this an HTTP triggered function or is this function triggered after a document changes on the database? Would you please expand on that?

Comment: @JuanGiacosa
i'm taking reference as pe the Doc https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that this function is set to use the Node 8 runtime, since support for async iterators was added in Node 10. The Pub/Sub library has only supported Node 10 and above since 2.0, so bumping the runtime version on the Firebase function should help:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version

Unfortunately I don't have enough points to ask for more details on the original question, but hopefully that helps!